# Display updated values on submission of a Form

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, html

I have a form similar to a profile center. On submission of the form, an InvokeUpdate call is made to update the record details. I have the form tag as 
 `<form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">`
After the submission the form reopens with the previously filled values instead of the updated ones. To get the updated values I have to manually refresh the button. 
Since these are asynchronous calls I thought adding a wait in between will solve the issue

```
   function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }}}
sleep(1000);
```

But this did not work, I still had to refresh manually. I tried increasing the time to 10 seconds still it didn't make a difference.
What can be done so that I don't have to manually refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked here was to redirect the page to some other page and then redirect it back to the required page. On submission, I made the form blur and made a modal visible which displayed a text like values are being submitted and then after 2 seconds I reloaded the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your invokeUpdate is server sided code that can only executes on page load.
This is why the refresh is necessary in your current setup.

As it stands this is your order of operations:

`enter data on form >  button click > form page load with prefilling > update`

in contrast, you need:

`enter data on form > button click > update > form page load with prefilling`

The easiest way to do this is a form/handler setup like described here.

[Issue with passing value to data extension from the marketing cloud page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312937/issue-with-passing-value-to-data-extension-from-the-marketing-cloud-page/312954#312954)

By isolating the update call to an external page, you're new order of operations will be:

`enter data on form > button click > Send the data to a handler (different page) > let the handler do the update on page load > redirect back to your form > form page load with prefilling of updated data`

Best to set up the handler as a code resource, which doesn't consume a supermessage on load.